# Why is the navigation and top section of my site pushed to the right on tablets?

Tags: android, html, ios, css

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the background of the top section and the navigation is being pushed to the left on tablets. What could be the problem?

**CSS:**

```
#header {
  background: #FFF;
  height: 69px;
  overflow: visible;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 29px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 0 8px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 0 8px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 0 8px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.section-gray {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

**META:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Live site: http://www.m2comm-semi.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should improve your style for smaller devices but for solving this problem you can add this in your style.

```
#signage .container > img {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    // Add max-width
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #header
  {
    height:auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with your breakpoints. The first one is set to **767px**:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  etc.
}
```

You will need to add more breakpoints to allow for the devices which may be larger than 767px.